# ListView padding on scrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scroll, padding

I want to add padding at top of ListView and after scrolling ListView i want to set padding to 0.

I've tried adding padding at top of ListView and Layout but both don't work.

Here's what I exactly want:

[image: Before scrolling]

(At top of ListView / Before scrolling)

[image: After scrolling]

(Scrolled down ListView / After scrolling)

Comment: it looks like you have some pinned header?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you have to set `android:clipToPadding="false"`

like this:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/your_listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:scrollbars="none" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: That is AWESOME, I was struggling was that and didn't knew about this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding header to list view where header can be a view that takes care of the padding.

listView.addHeaderView(header);